# What changes require to make my Restful services only accessible through https instead http?

Tags: rest, jboss, rest-security

I am able to hit my web service with Below URL:
http://localhost:8080/projectservices/route/rest/gethealth

But I want to force the app to access REST resource using https only as:
http://localhost:8080/projectservices/route/rest/gethealth

FYI, I am using jboss wildfly 10 server.
It will be very helpful if anyone over here will let me know what are the different approaches and you can also suggest me some link to get more understanding of it. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Close port 80? Only leave open port 443.

Comment: HTTP is accessed via port 80. HTTPS is accessed via 443. Your computer can be accessed from different ports (kind of like doors) simultaneously. An easy way to close HTTP access is to close that door (port 80). But, leave port 443 (the door to HTTPS) open. What operating system are u using?

Comment: Actually I am running the application in the local system on Jboss wildfly 
 Server and consuming the resource from POSTMAN. Now you let me know what i am suppose to do.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Jabari. I am using windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

http vs https is not dependent on Rest webservices. 
Enabling your application to be https need to be done at your server level. In your case - Jboss.

Im not familiar on how this can be done in Jboss, see if below helps:
https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/ssl-howto.html

Comment: I will have a look on the link you provided. Thanks for your comment :)